# how can i sort one array with 2 child using fork() in c

Tags: c, arrays, fork, sorting

example some array {2,8,9,10,21,32,1,6,3...}
first child take (data size / 2) and sort
second chile take (data size / 2) and sort after combine 2 child data and give us a sorted full data, is it possible with some algorithms?

Comment: If you want to make parralel sorting,wouldn't threads suffice?Then you do not have to worry about passing the data between workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are actually many parallel sorting algorithms existing.

Some interesting links with many different parallel sorting algorithms :

- [A Library of Parallel Algorithms](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/nesl/algorithms.html#sort)
- [Computer Programming Algorithms Directory](http://www.algosort.com/)
- [Sequential and parallel sorting algorithms](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/algoen.htm)

Some implementations :

- [Parallel quicksort implementation using MPI and PThreads](http://www.winlab.rutgers.edu/~pkataria/pdc.pdf)
- [Parallel Sorting Strategies](http://einstein.drexel.edu/~valliere/PHYS405/sort_algorithms/sort_algorithm.html)

But I advice you to search google with [parallel sorting algorithms](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&q=parallel+sorting+algorithms&btnG=Search) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using two processes for this is almost certainly not what you want to do.  You would have to find some way of passing the data back...